# OWIN OAuth and IIS Static Assets

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, static-files

I can't seem to find a good answer around authenticating my OAuth users to static assets in my Web API 2 application. I am using the default OWIN middleware that comes with the VS2013 SPA template. If I upload static content (such as thumbnails) to -

```
Content/{somesubdir}/upload.jpg
```

which can then be accessed by

```
http://{host}/Content/{somesubdir}/upload.jpg
```

How can I protect this file from public access, but allow users with a valid OAuth token access? Do I have to serve this file with a WebAPI controller? Is there a way to utilize IIS's static serving, but check the token first?

Comment: Adding the following line to the web.config, seems to allow for intercepting the requests -                                                                                       <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>                                                             but that defeats the purpose at first glance, since I would have to make a controller method that intercepts the request..

Comment: what's the reason you shy away from protecting the assets with Web API? Do you have a high scale scenario you are trying to address? If so I wouldn't put the files on your IIS server and rather use a blob or a CDN.

Comment: The app will not be very high scale, but it just seems very redundant to try and wrap a controller around a static asset. For example, If I wanted to change the location where the files are stored, I would need to refactor the controller signature etc.

Comment: exactly the other way around :) You can move the files to your hearts liking, but still keep the same URL. You can for example create a controller that handles all URLs starting with /content, then write standard code to access file from there, so you don't need any refactoring